# Left Join Yielding no results

Tags: sql, openedge

I'm coming across an issue where when I write a query as so:

```
SELECT a.v, b.w, c.x, d.y, e.z 
FROM a
JOIN b
on a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c
on a.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN d
on b.code=d.code
JOIN e
on a.n = e.n
WHERE
a.zone = 10
WITH (nolock)
```

I get several hundred results, but when I modify it to this:

```
SELECT a.v, b.w, c.x, d.y, e.z 
FROM a
JOIN b
on a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c
on a.id = c.id AND c.n = 0
LEFT JOIN d
on b.code=d.code AND d.n = 0
JOIN e
on a.n = e.n
WHERE
a.zone = 10
WITH (nolock)
```

I get zero results.

From my understanding of SQL and left joins, I feel that getting any results with the first query means I should definitely get at least one result with the second, if only one where fields from c and d are null. Does PROGRESS implement outer joins in an unusual manner?

Comment: i think it's because `b` is not a left join, when you join `d` to `b` this effects `'a'`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to figure out what the `c.n` and `d.n` values are.  Try something like this to figure out where your starting point is.

```
SELECT c.n, d.n, count(*)
FROM a
JOIN b
on a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c
on a.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN d
on b.code=d.code
JOIN e
on a.n = e.n
WHERE
a.zone = 10
group by c.n, d.n
```

Then you can adjust your query based on the result

Comment: The c.n, d.n, and a.zone comparisons are actually passed in as parameters to the query. It works when c.n and d.n match up with values in the database, but the idea of the left join is to make it work even when they don't. (They happen to be keys to a descriptive table that don't always exist)

Comment: not if you enter a value.  if you are trying to get where they don't match you need to look for a null not a zero. `c.n is null`